# Text is running below the page

Tags: page-breaking

I've seen similar questions but none address my specific situation. My text is running below the page, and continuing about 30 lines later on the next line.

I wasn't sure what tag to use because I'm not sure what's causing the problem.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

%Set Hebrew font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[series={A,B},noend]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph} %Put grammatical apparatus into a single paragraph
\Xwrapcontent[A]{\LR}
\Xlemmaseparator[A]{[} %Fixes the direction of the bracket
\firstlinenum*{1}
\linenumincrement*{1}
\setRlineflag{} %Removes R
\Xbeforeinserting[A]{\RTL}
\Xbhookgroup[A]{\flushright}

\def\linenumrepR#1{%
\begingroup%
\hebrewfont%
\hebrewnumeral{#1}%
\endgroup
}

\usepackage{bidi}
\makeatletter
\let\Afootnoterule=\right@footnoterule
\makeatother


\tolerance=10000 %Fix justification issues

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english} \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{cjhebrew} %I need this for using Hebrew in text commands

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}

\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
        Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. Left column text. 
    \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
        עמוד \edtext{ב׳.}{\Afootnote{Footnote.}} הטקסט של העמודה הזאת נמשך לשורה שנייה.
    \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tracked the problem down to `\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}`. Setting the option to `{normal}` gives you normally formatted text. Maybe you can develop it from here? My console also recommends loading `polyglossia` before `bidi`, although that does not change anything. (Run with XeLaTeX)

Comment: You shouldn't be using `cjhebrew` with a unicode setup.